# What should we do with unreleased soundtracks in anime song identification questions?

Tags: discussion

As you may know, [there are lots of unreleased soundtracks](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/44628/why-are-there-unreleased-soundtracks). However, these days, you can usually find an unofficial version of the track floating around online somewhere, presumably spliced together by someone using audio samples from various episodes. Or, in a few cases that I've seen, arranged from scratch by ear (e.g. [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nh8CS8PM7vk) and [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=t1qp9STVU4k)).

So, if a question asks about a song that wasn't officially released, but happens to have one of these unofficial versions floating around, is it okay to link to them?

I ask because I come across these types of questions a lot (e.g. [1](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/46157/a-happy-instrumental-song-which-plays-during-a-flashback-in-naruto-shippuden), [2](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/39650/whats-the-song-in-episode-479-called-when-naruto-and-iruka-are-at-the-swing-and), [3](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/43209/what-is-the-song-that-plays-when-lelouch-sees-the-memories-of-c-c-in-episode-11), [4](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/24140/what-is-the-name-of-the-track-playing-in-episode-14), [5](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/36681/what-is-the-name-of-song-from-code-geass-in-episode-5-when-the-lancelot-is-savin)). And recently, a couple of my answers of such a nature were deleted ([1](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/46806/a-sad-violin-song-in-most-of-flashback-scenes-like-obitos-flashback-and-the-sto/47275#47275), [2](https://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/44470/what-is-the-song-when-obito-attacked-naruto-and-sasuke-in-episode-378-of-naruto/47254#47254)). I've discussed this with the mod in question, and do agree with some of their concerns, and I've edited these answers accordingly. But the mod still had some misgivings about these answers, and suggested that these kinds of responses would be more appropriate as a comment.

I'll note that all of the other unreleased track answers that I've seen were by lower-rep users, so maybe we're doing it wrong...

So I wanted to clarify here: For questions requesting identification of a song that is an unreleased track, what is best practice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> questions requesting identification of a song that is an unreleased
>   track, what is best practice?

Answering it as such would be the best course of action. All though people should not jump the gun and state songs are unreleased without some research. If they really are unreleased, answering that it is unreleased would be the best answer.

> So, if a question asks about a song that wasn't officially released, but happens to have one of these unofficial versions floating around, is it okay to link to them?

I would be in favor of avoiding it, considering fan splicing often does not fall within [fair use](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fair_use) territory.
However, if you do use links, try to avoid making it too advertising. As that is what originally caught our attention.

As you seem to have addressed these issues in the answers you linked, I have also un-deleted these answers for you.